# Change file upload options provided by ios

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html

I am using below code to upload file from web view in ios.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

When I tap on this input tag it provides me options as

- Take Photo
- Choose existing photo
- cancel

Now, what I want is to add new option in above list as delete/remove like:

- Take Photo
- Choose existing photo
- remove
- cancel

Is this possible to achieve this either via javascript or objective-c?

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: thanks for reply, is there any reason for that?

Comment: the input type file is handled by the webview, you can't change how it works